# Meaning of 'b*****k'

Tags: word-meaning, offensive-language

What is the original word of **b*****k** without asterisks? Context is "stark b*****k naked"

Are there any English language dictionaries where curse words with asterisks are listed?

Comment: I doubt that such disguised swear words appear in any dictionaries; it's assumed that you can guess what word is meant.

Answer (score 7):

I imagine it's meant to be the British English slang "stark bollock naked".

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bollocks)

> **plural noun**
>
> A man's bollocks are his testicles.
>
> [British, informal, rude]

Comment: I don't think you need 'stark'. I mean, it's optional.

Comment: In Lexico, "bollock-naked" has its own entry: https://www.lexico.com/definition/bollock-naked

Comment: Multiple intensifiers are allowed. My father used to say that if he had to sit all the way through a George Formby film he would go 'stark, staring, raving mad'. This [same phrase](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/theroyalfamily/9591812/The-private-letters-of-Queen-Elizabeth-the-Queen-Mother.html) was used by the future Queen Mother in a letter to describe her joy at learning that her brother had not been killed in the battle of Loos in 1915.

Answer (score 0):

It might be "buck", though, since the word isn't obscene, it seems a little precious not to spell it out:

[American Heritage Dictionary "buck-naked"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=buck-naked)

> adv. & adj.
> Chiefly Southern US
> Without any clothes; nude.